# GWT and ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString()

Tags: gwt, tostring

I have a problem with the GWT compiler. When I add a next method to my entity class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
}
```

the compiler gave me next error:

```
ERROR: Deferred binding failed for 'com.mvp4g.client.Mvp4gModule'; expect subsequent failures
ERROR: Unable to load module entry point class plaut.wimc.avl.admin.client.Admin (see associated exception for details)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.mvp4g.client.Mvp4gModule' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
```

When I remove it, all works fine. I don't understand why gave me compiler such error. This `toString` method is used in roo [IDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming#Inter-type_declarations)'s too and there is no such error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Java code used in the client side needs to be able to compile to JavaScript. `ReflectionToStringBuilder` uses reflection which isn't available in JavaScript so this method can't be used in your client side code.

This compile error refers to the fact that all Java code must be accessed by the GWT copmiler  via `path` parameters in GWT module files and must be available in source format. In this case no GWT module file is present, hence the error, because the compiler can't find the sources for the `ReflectionToStringBuilder` method. Although you can create such a file for this specific case and add the sources, it won't work as reflection won't work.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but how it it is possible, that in roo generated projects this works? Do you think that the aspectJ compiler translate this functions?

Comment: Can it be that in roo this class is only used in server side code? That would work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with ReflectionToStringBuilder. Is it a GWT module? If yes, then it needs to be added an inherited module in your project's *.gwt.xml

Comment: No it isn't GWT module, its apache artifact: org.apache.common:commons-lang3

Comment: @user1289877 Please read https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsClient (very first paragraph, particularly its last sentence)

Comment: I think you cannot use commons-lang in GWT yet. There is gwt-commons-lang(http://code.google.com/p/gwt-commons-lang/) project. But I don't see any activity inside it. Also, there is a old post(http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/msg/dead7dd8032aae1f?pli=1) in Google groups which says that you cannot use commons-lang in GWT project for client side.